# Python for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a txt file with data like this:

```
(NAME|RANGE|PASSANGERS)
Airbus A330-200|12000|263
Airbus A321-200|4600|200
Airbus A320-200|5500|162
Airbus A319-100|5700|132
Embraer 190|4445|106
ATR 72-600|1529|70
```

and i need to compare the number in the second column between every line and then print the NAME of the plane with the higher RANGE number (Need to print the NAME but have to compare and order it from highest RANGE to lowest RANGE). So far i have this:

```
f = open("./dados/aeronaves.txt","r")
d=[]
c=[]
tempList=[]
for line in f:
    a =(line.strip().split('|'))
    b = c.append(a)
    d.append(int(a[1]))
    d.sort()
for i in range(0,len(c)):
    print(c[i])
    print(c[i][1])
f.close()
```

but i dont know how to do it with the for in range but it has to be with it...

HELP

Comment: thx @melpomene im new to this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

```
all_planes = []
f = open("./dados/aeronaves.txt","r")
for line in f.readlines()[1:]: #skip title line
    plane = line.strip().split('|')
    all_planes.append(plane)
all_planes = sorted(all_planes, key=lambda x: x[1])
for p in all_planes:
    print(p[0])
```

Comment: That's not in descending order, is it? I think you need `reverse=True`.

Comment: yeah thats ascending order, just add a negative symbol before x[1] in the sorted statement. reverse=True works

Comment: Or use `reversed()`.

Comment: @Ouroborus That's less efficient than just using the right sorting comparison.

Comment: That works but it skips one line in the txt file @Einstein

EDIT: i failed to notice the comment on the code nvm

Comment: @Raizan It's meant to skip `(NAME|RANGE|PASSANGERS)`. Remove `[1:]` if you don't want that.

Comment: @Einstein i was almost smashing my head against the keyboard to try to make this work for 6 hours ahah thank you very much! i have a lot to learn...

Comment: Feel free to message me if you need python help

Comment: ok you gotta give me more than that. Did it error out? what was the error?

Comment: @Einstein it just started putting number where they dont belong like: when it runs insted of being in descending order they are like this:
11065
12000
13450
15190
1529
15844
4445
4600
5500
5700

Comment: @Einstein and because of that the names that belond to the numbers are not in the order that i wanted

Comment: try putting int around the values:
    all_planes = sorted(all_planes, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)

Comment: @Einstein you are a genius, it worked! Thank you very much

Comment: @Einstein ok... i dont know what happens to this code... now its saying "IndexError: list index out of range"
all i did was add 'time.slepe(2)' 'z = input("\nPress a key to go back: ")'

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answers work, i would ve preferred namedtuples and attrgetter with heapq in the long run. Here is what i would ve done,

```
from operator import attrgetter
from collections import namedtuple
Plane = namedtuple("Plane","name range passengers")

with open('./dados/aeronaves.txt','r') as f:
    f.readline() #needed to read the first row
    planes = [Plane(*line.strip().split('|')) for line in f]

planes.sort(key=attrgetter('range'),reverse=True) #use heapq for more control
# print them all
print(planes) #or loop through and print

#use heapq for more control
import heapq
print(heapq.nsmallest(len(planes),planes,key=attrgetter('range')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the elements using the following one liner statement.

```
sorted_list = sorted([(line.strip().split('|')) for line in f], key=lambda k: int(k[1]))
```